# Using dlsym() to look for a variable in a statically linked library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, static-libraries, dlsym

We have a program that links in a number of static libraries, which may or may not define a number of symbols depending on compilation options.  On OS X, we use `dlsym(3)` with a NULL handle to obtain the symbol addresses.  However, on Linux, `dlsym(3)` always returns NULL.

Consider a trivial program (sources below) that links in a static library containing a function and a variable and tries to print their addresses.  We can check that the program contains the symbols:

```
$ nm -C test | grep "test\(func\|var\)"
0000000000400715 T testFunc
0000000000601050 B testVar
```

However, when the program is run, neither can be located:

```
$ ./test
testVar: (nil)
testFunc: (nil)
```

Is what we are trying to do possible on Linux, using glibc's implementation of `dlsym(3)`?

## Makefile

(Sorry about the spaces)

```
LDFLAGS=-L.
LDLIBS=-Wl,--whole-archive -ltest -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl

libtest.o: libtest.c libtest.h
    libtest.a: libtest.o
test: test.o libtest.a
clean:
    -rm -f test test.o libtest.o libtest.a
```

## libtest.h

```
#pragma once
extern void *testVar;
extern int testFunc(int);
```

## libtest.c

```
#include "libtest.h"
void *testVar;
int testFunc(int x) { return x + 42; }
```

## test.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  void *handle = dlopen(NULL, 0);
  void *symbol = dlsym(handle, "testVar");
  printf("testVar: %p\n", symbol);
  symbol = dlsym(handle, "testFunc");
  printf("testFunc: %p\n", symbol);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Totally unrelated, but naming a program `test` in a POSIX environment is a big source of problems, as there is a *standard command* also named `test`, often built into modern shells.

Comment: True! However, if you have `.` in your `PATH` then you deserve what you get. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should link your program with `-rdynamic` (or `--export-dynamic` for [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html)) so

```
LDFLAGS += -rdynamic -L.
```

Then all the symbols are in the dynamic symbol table, the one used by `dlsym`

BTW, the [`visibility` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) could be of interest.

Comment: For those, like me, who didn't know (from the manual): _`-rdynamic`: Pass the flag `-export-dynamic` to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some uses of `dlopen` or to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program._